# Missing Norwegian car ferries in OSMnx

Tags: python, gis, networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to create a driving network locally using OSMnx for all of Norway. However, I am struggling to get car ferries to work correctly.

First of all, they don't get downloaded automatically, so I have to separately identify ferries using `custom_filter='["route"~"ferry"]'`. However, this includes both passenger ferries and car ferries, and there is no intuitive way to filter out car ferries only. Furthermore, it seems as though a lot of important car ferries are missing. An example being the ferry going from Dragsvik to Vangsnes, which can be seen in the OSM route network here:
[OpenStreetMap.org route](https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_car&route=61.2096%2C6.5361%3B61.1745%2C6.6373#map=13/61.1975/6.6270).
But does not appear using the following code:

```
center_point =  (61.19516867153809, 6.601287878776234)
G_balestrand_ferries = ox.graph.graph_from_point(center_point, dist=10000, dist_type='bbox',network_type='all',  custom_filter='["route"~"ferry"]', retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=True)
G_balestrand_all = ox.graph.graph_from_point(center_point, dist=10000, dist_type='bbox',network_type='all', retain_all=True, truncate_by_edge=True)
m = folium.Map(location=center_point, zoom_start=12, )
ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_balestrand_all, nodes=False).explore(m=m, color="blue",)
ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_balestrand_ferries, nodes=False).explore(m=m, color="red")
```

Can anyone help me properly construct my graph network? Are these really missing or am I not fetching them correctly?

Thanks,
Trygve

Comment: Can you provide the OSM ID of the ferry you're missing?

Comment: These are examples of the ferries that are missing:
[10120194,
 38086827,
 14329891,
 38086827,
 10120194,
 10120194,
 10120194,
 10120194,
 10120194,
 10120194,
 14329891,
 14329891,
 10120194,
 14329891,
 10120194,
 10120194,
 38086827,
 38086827,
 38086827,
 38086827]

I found them by rewriting some code in _overpass.py and querying for f'["route"="ferry"]["motor_vehicle"!~"no"]'). However, I'm not sure if they are properly connected everywhere. But I can't query "driving" and get car ferries as well, unless I combine them.There is also no intuitive way of adding speed